is_valid() function of the authentication form is not working when the credential is wrong
I have extended the built in authentication form to use bootstrap naming LoginForm. If the user gives wrong credential, I want to show message that "Wrong Credential".But the is_valid() function only work when the credential is (username,password) is exactly the same. Let's say i put username right but wrong password, then the is_valid() function doesn't work.As a result i cant show the message that the password is wrong. But I have created another form by subclassing forms.Form. in that case the is_valid() faunction works for wrong credential too and shows the message for wrong username and password.
this is my form.
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = UsernameField(
        widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off','class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter your email'})
        )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_('Password'),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off','class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter your password'})
        )

this is the views.py
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('1')
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
            print('2')
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                print('3')

                return redirect('registration')
            else:
                print('4')
                messages.warning(request,'Wrong Credentials!')
        else:  # Use form.errors for displaying errors
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        print('get')
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request,'account/login.html',{'form':form})

since this form does not work. for testing purpose I've created another form. and this works fine and shows the error message of "Wrong credentials" if any of the field does not match the username and password.
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    username = forms.CharField(max_length=150,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"autofocus": True,'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter your Email',}))

    password = forms.CharField(max_length=150, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"autocomplete": "current-password",'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter your password',}))

Admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

from .models import CustomUser

# Register your models here.
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    list_display = ["email", "username", "is_staff"]
    list_filter = ["is_superuser"]
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {"fields": ["email", "password"]}),
        ("Personal info", {"fields": ["first_name","last_name"]}),
        ("Permissions", {"fields": ["is_superuser"]}),
    ]
    add_fieldsets = [
        (
            None,
            {
                "classes": ["wide"],
                "fields": ["email", "username", "password1", "password2"],
            },
        ),
    ]
    search_fields = ["email"]
    ordering = ["email"]
    filter_horizontal = []
admin.site.register(CustomUser, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)


what's the error dump look like?

it doesn't show any error. the problem is, the code does not enter the the is_valid() function if the credentials are not exactly the same. if i give right username but wrong password, it should still execute the is_valid() function. but it doesn't work in authentication form too, as a result my warning message is not displayed. but it works with another form i've create from forms.Form.

in views.py, change the form = LoginForm(data=request.POST) to form =  LoginForm(data=request.POST) inline with this post

still doesn't work according to the post.

another suggestion in that post:
form = LoginForm(request.POST, request.POST)

tried this one too. it only execute the is_valide() function when when I give the username and password accurate.

@NazmulHaque: how did you register the user?

I have extended BaseUserAdmin and unregister Group. I am attaching the admin.py above too.
